# How do dynamic linkers/loaders resolve symbols?

Tags: linker, dynamic-linking

I'm a CS student, and I'm doing a project on shared libraries and dynamic linking/loading. One of the questions I have to answer is how symbols are resolved with dynamic linking/loading. I've scoured the internet and haven't been able to find anything conclusive. I understand different linkers may resolve symbols differently across different operating systems. I'm just looking for a general, windows-based answer; how are symbols resolved in dynamic linking?

Thank You!

Comment: The question is for  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ (automatic form doesn't allow such selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's stick on Windows. I'll answer in a few words and then vote for moving this question to CS site instead of main SO.

First, dynamic linking can be at program start (prelinked variant) and when program code explicitly requests some library load. While the same DLLs are used there, details differ.

Prelinked variant will work with so called import library that is static but contains special thunks (AKA trampolines) that are replaced with jumps to real code when dynamic loader attaches a real library (DLL file). For linkers that aren't aware of dynamic loading, import library is enough to still provide dynamic linking - that how it appeared in DOS/Windows. The calling code could be ignorant of details if the code is provided by static or dynamic library.

On-the-fly loading is using methods like LoadLibrary to load the library (and activate it) and GetProcAddress to get pointer of real function implementation. In that case, application (or another library) is aware of details of this mechanism.

I hope this brief is enough to provide you with enough words for further delving.